# Что можно рассказать про Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

На практику задали обзор компьютерной программы Eclipse. Хорошая среда разработки, пользуюсь несколько месяцев, но 5 минут подряд рассказывать не смогу. Что посоветуете сказать об этой программе, ее функциях и т.д.?

Comment: Я думал он устарел лет 6-8 назад :D  И я сейчас серьёзно

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Я только недавно начал использовать эту программу. Пишу на ней несложный проекты на jave и для андроида. Мне импонирует то что не нужно устанавлить медленное и неповоротливое Андроид Студио. Эклипс для старых машин и маленких хобийных проектов подходит идеально.